# access the react server on cloud9 from PC browser

Tags: reactjs, aws-cloud9

I want to try a react hands-on on cloud9. However, I can not access to the server on my PC browser.

Detail:

I've run an AWS Cloud9 environment with the default setting.
Next run these commands.

```
npx create-react-app handson-react-2019 --typecscript
npm start
```

Then it says.

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view  hands-on-react-2019 in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:8080/
  On Your Network:  http://172.31.5.16:8080/

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

I believe this is very normal to react way.

Problem is, How to access this running server with my PC browser?
If I'm developing on my Mac, it's easy just access http://localhost:8080 that's all. How to do it on cloud9 environment?

I tried:
- 1. http://localhost:8080 : ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT as the server is running on the EC2 machine.
- 2. http://172.31.5.16:8080 : (This is the IP address of EC2 machine.) not working. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
- 3. Preview - show Active servers: Nothing I can see.

[image: show Active servers]

I've read many answers on the internet about c9users.io that's old information.
Give me any information about CURRENT cloud9 way.

Answer (score 0):

I got working with `ngrok http 8080`. 
I don't think this is expected way for AWS Cluod9 but I can start developing...